# How do you take a Verizon iPhone 4 CDMA phone and get it connected to Straight Talk?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I purchased a nice black Verizon iPhone 4 (CDMA) which has it's contract fulfilled.

What steps do I go through to get it connected to Walmart's Straight Talk on the Verizon towers?

Comment: Have you talked with the guys down at Walmart? They might take care of it easily.

Answer (score -1):

The iPhone 4 built for Verizon's network is a CDMA-only device that is not capable of operating on a GSM network that requires a SIM card, such as StraightTalk (which uses T-Mobile's network). It will never work. It does not have the radios built into it that would be necessary.